# Isdate function in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

Is there any isdate function available in redshift. I want to pass a variable or column into the function and find out whether that variable or column value are date or not. If there is any Udf available for that please update same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the column is of type `DATE`, then it is a date (but could be `null`).

Any other type of column is, therefore, *not* a `DATE`.

You can, however, convert types, such as taking a `VARCHAR` and try converting it to a date (eg `other_column::DATE`). If it doesn't work, I think it would be `null` (but please test it).

**Update:**

You can use `MAXERROR` in the `COPY` command to tell Redshift to continue loading rows even if there are errors. The rows will be skipped, but you can look in [STL_LOAD_ERRORS - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) to view the errors.

If you do not want to skip the rows, you will need to load the date into a `VARCHAR` field (which will not cause an error) and later you will need to convert the `VARCHAR` into a `DATE`. The preferred method for this is to copy the existing table into a new table (`SELECT INTO...`), with the column conversion. (Doing an `UDPATE` in Redshift is inefficient because it causes rows to be deleted and reinserted.)

Comment: I have checked the solution and found that if value not successfully convert to date then the the process failed with redshift error that unable to convert date format. But I don't want to make the process failed I want to segrate correct date format with incorrect one.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have loaded the data in varchar field so that there should not be any error. But during next step when I am trying o distinguished between correct date and junk date that time I am facing error. So I need something like Oracle or sql server function which tell me in binary whether the passing variable is date or not.